# How To Change Attributes in List of CustomObject in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am having following Case class

```
case class BIC( id: Option[Int], name: String, description: Option[String],
                                    bId: Option[Int], amount: BigDecimal,
                                    createdBy: Option[Int], createdAt: Option[DateTime] )
```

my REST-API url is like following

```
POST    /api/v3/user/2/bid/23/create
```

Now userId = 2 and bId = 23 are coming From URL path params
I am also having List of BIC incoming from POST Request JSON which does not contain userId and bId

I am directly injecting incoming JSON to List[BIC], but all the objects in this list doesn't have createdBy (userId) and bId set.

if I want to set these 2 parameters in each BIC objects of List[BIC] what is the approach I should follow?

```
            val lsttemp:List[BIC] = bicList
            val lst:List[BIC]
            lsttemp.foreach(x=>{
              x.bId=inId
              x.createdBy = userId
              lst.add(x)
            })
```

I am trying above code but its not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Case classes` provide `copy` method which helps you to achieve your goal:

```
val lst = bicList.map( _.copy(bId=inId, createdBy = userId))
```

Comment: Thanks @Sergey Lagutin